# generating api in json

Tags: json

I am trying to generate a common api for my website. I got separate code for different services like Twitter, YouTube and flickr. Can someone tell me how to sort them all together by date?

Answer (score 2):

Convert them all to some standard measurement, like a Unix timestamp. Then you can use numeric sorting methods.

Comment: Do take note of the date timezone though. I've not tried it but could be rather tricky.